# How can I create an object of this class?

Tags: java

In class `B`, how can I create an object of class `A` other than the process of object creation (i.e. without creating an object having `null`)?

```
class A
  {
    public int one;  
   A(A a)
    {
      a.one=1;
    }
  }
class B
  {
   public static void main(String...args)
     {
     //now how to create an object of class A over here.
     }
  }
```

Comment: What context? Is this a homework question? Interview question? Is `A` editable?

Comment: This isn,t a homework question.i had a thought in my mind about this question.A is surely not editable.

Comment: @ Emmad thanks for ur comment but in java this can be done easily

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot normally do this in Java.

However, it's possible with heavy cheating. **Don't do this in production code.** But for the sake of argument:

1) With [Mockito](http://code.google.com/p/mockito/) (But won't work with a security manager):

```
import org.mockito.Mockito;

class B {

    public static void main(String... args) {
        A mockedA = Mockito.mock(A.class);
        A realA = new A(mockedA);
        System.out.println(realA);
    }
}
```

2) Here's [another way to do it overriding `finalize()`](http://wouter.coekaerts.be/2012/puzzle-chicken-solution).

Comment: +1: For thinking outside the box, and for posting a very relevant link. Not sure if the OP is looking for this sort of solution, but very interesting and educational nonetheless!

Answer (score 7):

To construct an object of type A you need to pass to the constructor either a reference to another object of type A, or else the null reference. So you have only two options:

```
A a1 = new A(null);
A a2 = new A(a1);
```

The first time you create an object of type `A` you must use the null reference because you don't have any other objects of type `A`.

---

**Update**

After you changed your question, I don't think it's possible to construct an object of type `A`.

Comment: yes this could be done but isn,t this more or less the same method used above.

Comment: wat if i want to do some thing with the object's properties in the constructor.

Comment: @saurabh You can simply use `a.propertyName` in the constructor as you would normally, but you'll have to check whether or not `a` is `null` first. If you can't change the code of class `A`, this check should already be in place. If it isn't, then I question the usefulness of the class.

Comment: This will throw **NullPointerException**. When you spicify **A a1 = new A(null)**,  then in the constructor, **a.one=1** will throw **NPE**.

Comment: @ Priyank the solution given by Mark was according to my previous version of code.Mark was not aware of the current functionality of the constructor while writing the code A a1=new A(null);

Answer (score 5):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to create an object a without having to pass it a pre-existing object of the same type.

To do so you have to add a constructor to class A that does not take a parameter of type A or modify the existing one:

```
class A
    {
        A() {
            // Constructor logic.
        }
        A(A a) {
            // Constructor logic when passing an existing object of the same type, perhaps to create a clone.
        }
    }
```

If for some reason you can't modify class A, you'll have to follow Mark Byers' answer and pass a null reference to the constructor.

---

**Update**

With the update to your code, this problem (or thought experiment) is unsolvable: class A can not be instantiated as written.

Comment: the default constructor is intentionally not there.

Answer (score 3):

Only way to create A object is by giving him other A object in constructor, but that other A object also needs another A object in constructor. This will stop only when you put null reference in constructor.

### Edit

My answer was based on your previous version of code. Now you can't create object because you can't put `null` in constructor (null desn't have `one` field). If you want to create A object, you have to do test for null in constructor like `if (a!=null){ a.one=1;}` and pass null or already created A object in constructor.

Comment: but if i pass a null at any instant then the constructor will surely throw a null pointer exception.

Answer (score 2):

If A is sealed (not editable) you could only extend that class and give the one a default constructor to pass it into a new instance of A. There is no other solution without modifying the source code of A.

Comment: I think A can't be extended. Constuctor in this form throws NullPointerException and default constructor is blocked/doesn't exist.

Answer (score 2):

You can not instantiate A in your example. It is a chicken and egg problem. You need an instance of A to create an instance of A, but you can not create an instance of A without having an instance of A.

So, without changes to A (be it either adding a 'null' check or adding a default constructor) you can not create an instance of A in this scenario.